# How to save cookies for Dark/Light Mode Toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the [W3Scholls Dark Mode Toggle](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_dark_mode) for my webiste and it's working perfectly well.

But just after I refresh my page the default view that is Day Mode is shown.

This is [Webpage Test Page.](https://freeairdrop.io/airdrop/bannertest.html)

How can I set cookies so that if a user selects dark mode then the page opens in dark mode by default?

Also, How can this be applied for the whole website so that the user need not press the button every time he opens the page.

Comment: did you try: `localStorage.setItem("theme", "night")` this will keep user settings in the browser's localstorage. and also you will not loose it on page reload.

Comment: Let me check if this works

Comment: No... This doesn't works

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `localStorage` for this.

```
// On page load set the theme.
(function() {
  let onpageLoad = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "";
  let element = document.body;
  element.classList.add(onpageLoad);
  document.getElementById("theme").textContent =
    localStorage.getItem("theme") || "light";
})();

function themeToggle() {
  let element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");

  let theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
  if (theme && theme === "dark-mode") {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "");
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark-mode");
  }

  document.getElementById("theme").textContent = localStorage.getItem("theme");
}
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="themeToggle()">Theme Toggle</button>
<div id="theme"></div>
```

Comment: Let me give a try on this. @Sohail

Comment: I am using the same code by W3schools in which " onclick="myFunction()" ". So do I need to replace that themeToggle() with myFunction() ?

Comment: Please suggest edits on my code : https://pastebin.com/raw/FJdESGjG @Sohail I can't understand the script's use of light and dark.

Comment: I am not able to understand how to use codesandbox.

Comment: @Sohail Hi. (not related to the question) just curious how did you move to chat mode from this question and answers page. can you please tell me the steps.?