# Save Dark mode to local storage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've added dark mode to my website and it works perfectly

But just after I refresh my page the default view that is Day Mode is shown.

so, is there any way to save this preferences?

HTML

```
    <body>
    <div class="main-page" id="main-page">
        <a id="darkmode" onclick="myFunction()" style="display: block; position: fixed; z-index: 2147483647;"><span><i class="fa fa-moon" id="darkIcon"></i></span></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
    function myFunction() {
    var element = document.getElementById("main-page");
    var icon = document.getElementById("darkIcon");
    element.classList.toggle("active-dark");

    if (element.className == ["main-page active-dark"]){
        if (icon.className == "fa fa-moon"){
            icon.classList.toggle("fa-sun");
        }else {
            icon.classList.toggle("fa-moon");

        }

    }
    if (element.className == "main-page"){
        if (icon.className == "fa fa-sun"){
            icon.classList.toggle("fa-moon");
        }else {
            icon.classList.toggle("fa-sun");

        }


    }
}
```

**NOTE :**

To activate dark mode i just add "active-dark" after "main-page" class and to disable dark mode i just remove the class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a session using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257631/how-to-create-a-session-using-javascript)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { /* adjust css for dark mode */ }` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save cookies for Dark/Light Mode Toggle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60037491/how-to-save-cookies-for-dark-light-mode-toggle)

Answer (score 2):

In your `myFunction` function save state of darkmode in `localStorage`

```
function myFunction() {
     localStorage.setItem('isDarkMode', true);
```

And in your JS add following line

Just make sure DOM is loaded before execution of this line

```
if (localStorage.getItem('isDarkMode') === 'true') {
    document.getElementById('main-page').classList.add('active-dark');
}
```

Comment: could you please give me a full example because i'm beginner in js

Comment: Full example? You just have add these two lines in your code. First line in your `myFunction`. Well the second if condition you can add multiple places. 1) `DOMContentLoaded` callback 2) At the end of your body in `<script>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code to auto-detect user dark mode and save it to local storage for keeping the current mode throughout the session.

The below code will run when the user clicks the dark mode toggle button. Make sure you create the CSS class for `.dark-mode` with the required CSS code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $("#dark-mode").click(function () {
      $("body").toggleClass("dark-mode");
      if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty('isDarkMode')) {
         if (localStorage.getItem('isDarkMode') === 'true') {
            localStorage.setItem('isDarkMode', 'false');
         }
         else if (localStorage.getItem('isDarkMode') === 'false') {
            localStorage.setItem('isDarkMode', 'true');
         }
      }
   })


   if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
      if (!(localStorage.hasOwnProperty('isDarkMode'))) {
         $("body").addClass("dark-mode");
         localStorage.setItem('isDarkMode', true);
      }
   }
   else {
      if (!(localStorage.hasOwnProperty('isDarkMode'))) {
         $("body").removeClass("dark-mode");
         localStorage.setItem('isDarkMode', false);
      }
   }

   if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty('isDarkMode')) {

      if (localStorage.getItem('isDarkMode') === 'true') {
         $("body").addClass("dark-mode");
      }
      else if (localStorage.getItem('isDarkMode') === 'false') {
         $("body").removeClass("dark-mode");
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are using jQuery since you are using $. I wasn't sure what the $ meant and my browser also complained about it. Had to do some research and discovered this was jQuery.

Comment: If you can't figure it out at first glance, it means you don't have enough knowledge of JavaScript. Every developer knows it's jQuery code, so I didn't mention it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on where you render (generate the html) your page.

If you render it on the client (browser) you can save it in the session storage:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("darkmode", true)
```

and then get it when loading your page via:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("darkmode")
```

If you render it on the server you can save it in a session variable. This depends however heavily on your server side library / language which you use to implement this. You would then make a request to the server in order to set this variable.

An alternative is to use a cookie. You can read this on the server and on the client.
You can set it like this.

```
document.cookie = "darkmode=true"
```

EDIT:

You should use the local storage since it will outlive the session.

```
localStorage.setItem("darkmode", true)
```

and

```
localStorage.getItem("darkmode")
```

Answer (score 0):

My take:

```
                        <style>
                        .dark-mode {
                          background-color: black;
                          color: white;
                        }
                        </style>
                    <div>
                        <button class="btn btn-light btn-sm" onclick="myFunction()">Toggle dark mode</button>
                        <script>
                        function myFunction() {
                            if (localStorage.getItem('isDarkMode')=='true'){
                                localStorage.setItem('isDarkMode', false)} 
                                else 
                                {localStorage.setItem('isDarkMode', true)}
                                toggle_color();
                        };

                        function toggle_color(){
                            if (localStorage.getItem('isDarkMode')=='true'){
                            
                            document.getElementById('main').classList.add('dark-mode');
                        }
                        if (localStorage.getItem('isDarkMode') === 'false'){
                                
                            document.getElementById('main').classList.remove('dark-mode');
                            };
                        }
                        toggle_color()
                        </script>
                    <div>
```