# How do i remember a users dark mode choice?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a little site showcasing what I have made. However im not sure how to make sure my website remembers a users dark mode choice.

I have read other stack overflow questions where the answer was cookies or localStorage. Though i dont quite understand how to implement this sadly. Since im pretty new to javascript.

My dark mode is selected via a switch. When the switch is clicked the entire page will get a black background color and the text will change from black to white.

I have the dark mode switch working on all 3 sites. However i cant seem to make the website remember the users dark mode choice. So everytime the page is refreshed or the user clicks on a different nested site. The site reverts back to the default state which is white.

Every page has its own function since i need to highlight a paragraph in the header tag. To make sure the user knows what page they are on.

How do i save the dark mode input and read it across all the 3 nested sites so it doesnt reset when a new page is visited?

Any input is very much appreciated

Edit: I dont know if its worth mentioning. however the default colour for the website is white with black text. all dark mode does is change the color. though im not sure how to remember that user choice.

```js
function toggleDarkMode1() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
  var test1 = document.getElementById("changeMe1");
  test1.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
  var test2 = document.getElementById("change2");
  test2.classList.toggle("dark-mode-header");
  var test3 = document.getElementById("changeMe3");
  test3.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

```css
.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.dark-mode-header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="./resources/nestedPages/projectsPage/index.html" id="changeMe1">
    <p class="projectsHeader" id="change1">Projects</p>
  </a>
  <a href="./index.html" id="changeMe2">
    <p class="aboutMeHeader" id="change2">About me</p>
  </a>
  <a href="./resources/nestedPages/contactPage/index.html" id="changeMe3">
    <p class="contactHeader">Contact</p>
  </a>
</header>
<div class="DMDiv">
  <p>Dark mode</p>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="darkmode" onclick="toggleDarkMode1()">
    <span class="slider"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Method #1 - store the setting somewhere, eg. a cookie or localStorage, and read it back out when the page next loads. Method #2 - use the host devices' dark mode setting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50840168/519413

Comment: Why not use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62047483/save-dark-mode-to-local-storage-in-javascript

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60037491/how-to-save-cookies-for-dark-light-mode-toggle

Comment: Proper method is CSS: `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { }` and nothing more. Because dark/light mode have nothing in common with Themes appearance colors

Comment: Also, keep in mind that using LocalStorage or cookies for this binds the usage to a specific system. This will not be synced to other devices - for example, setting the dark mode on your phone does not set the dark mode for your PC

Answer (score 1):

You could use cookies/local storage. You'd need to store the updated value whenever you change colour, and would need to check it on page load. I personally prefer `localStorage` so will be using that, but the concept is the same for cookies!

The one thing I would do differently is adding a wrapper around `toggleDarkMode` so that we can reuse this code for changing the page colour on load, without it changing our stored value

```
//check for value on page load
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode") == "true"; //returns stored value or null if not set

if(darkMode){
  toggleDarkMode(); //I'm assuming your page starts in light mode, so a call to toggle should switch everything over!
}

//new wrapper function
const updateDarkMode = () => {
  darkMode = !darkMode; //invert our variable
  localStorage.setItem("darkMode", darkMode); //save it in local storage
  toggleDarkMode(); //now update our styles!
}
```

The only other change you would need to make, is to reference the dark mode wrapper in your HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="darkmode" onclick="updateDarkMode()">
```

---

Edit: Another good thing to do would be to check if the user prefers light/dark mode, and you can set up your default state that way. We can do this using the `window.matchMedia` function, which would see your initial loading change to

```
const getInitialState = () => {
  const initialValue = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");

  if(initialValue === null){
    return window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;
  }

  return initialValue == "true";
}

let darkMode = getInitialState();
```

---

### Edit 30/11/2023 - Setting the checkbox

This is 100% my bad as my original code never did it! Fortunately it's relatively straightforward - once we've figured out if they want dark or light, we then need to set whether the checkbox is checked. Add this to the end of your script:

```
let darkMode = getInitialState(); //last line of the existing script
document.getElementById("darkmode").checked = darkMode;
```

That should be it!

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the quick reply!

I tried adding the code. Now i get this reply:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
    at toggleDarkMode (script.js:3:13)
    at script.js:15:3
toggleDarkMode @ script.js:3
(anonymous) @ script.js:15

3index.html:42 Uncaught ReferenceError: updateDarkMode is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:42:81)
onclick @ index.html:42

Im not sure if i have done something wrong. i replaced previous input. with new.

            <input type="checkbox" id="darkmode" onclick="updateDarkMode()">

Comment: Hi @green-seen, sorry to hear it's not quite working for you! Without seeing your code I'm not 100% sure what the problem could be, but I've combined the code from your question and my answer into this JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/fopcsn2u/3/ - if this doesn't help then please let me know if there's any other way I can help!

Comment: Hi @Luke. Thanks so much! I looked over my code again and noticed that i was forgetting to add the script tag at the end instead of the beginning. Im pretty embarresed. Though thanks a bunch! I only have one issue now and that is that the switch that i use resets after i reload or switch between pages. even though dark mode is retained. Is there anything i could do? Im using the switch from w3 schools

link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp
Thanks a bunch again!!

Comment: Hey @green-seen, congratulations on getting it working! :) It's entirely my bad as I seem to have forgotten all about setting the initial state of the checkbox, but I've just updated my answer - hopefully that should fix it for you?

Answer (score -1):

Let's create a single function that can be reused across your pages to handle dark mode toggling and persistence. Here's the modified code:

```js
function toggleDarkMode() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
  document.getElementById("changeMe1").classList.toggle("dark-mode");
  document.getElementById("change2").classList.toggle("dark-mode-header");
  document.getElementById("changeMe3").classList.toggle("dark-mode");

  // Check if dark mode is enabled and save the preference in localStorage
  var darkModeEnabled = element.classList.contains("dark-mode");
  localStorage.setItem("darkMode", darkModeEnabled);
}

function applyDarkModePreference() {
  var darkModeEnabled = localStorage.getItem("darkMode") === "true";
  var element = document.body;

  // Apply dark mode preference
  if (darkModeEnabled) {
    element.classList.add("dark-mode");
    document.getElementById("changeMe1").classList.add("dark-mode");
    document.getElementById("change2").classList.add("dark-mode-header");
    document.getElementById("changeMe3").classList.add("dark-mode");
  }
}

// Call the applyDarkModePreference function when the page loads
applyDarkModePreference();
```

Now, you can use the toggleDarkMode function for the dark mode switch, and the applyDarkModePreference function to apply the user's preference when the page loads. Include these functions in each of your pages, and they should work consistently across the site.

Comment: hello. Thanks for the quick reply! 

i tried to implement the code above here. and corrected the html reference to the javascript function call. Though it still doesn't work. Im not sure if i've done something wrong. I copied the code and put it in instead of my own on every script.js file and looked through it but it still doesn't work sadly.

Answer (score -1):

To persist the user's dark mode choice across different pages, you can use `localStorage` in JavaScript. Here's a modified version of your `toggleDarkMode1` function that saves the dark mode state in the local storage:

```js
function toggleDarkMode1() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
  var test1 = document.getElementById("changeMe1");
  test1.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
  var test2 = document.getElementById("change2");
  test2.classList.toggle("dark-mode-header");
  var test3 = document.getElementById("changeMe3");
  test3.classList.toggle("dark-mode");

  // Save dark mode state to localStorage
  var isDarkMode = element.classList.contains("dark-mode");
  localStorage.setItem("darkMode", isDarkMode);
}

// Check the initial dark mode state on page load
function checkDarkMode() {
  var isDarkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");
  var element = document.body;
  if (isDarkMode === "true") {
    element.classList.add("dark-mode");
  } else {
    element.classList.remove("dark-mode");
  }
}

// Call checkDarkMode on page load
checkDarkMode();
```

This modified code adds a call to `localStorage.setItem` to save the dark mode state whenever the user toggles the switch. It also includes a new function `checkDarkMode` that reads the dark mode state from `localStorage` on page load and applies the appropriate class to the body element.

Make sure to call `checkDarkMode()` when each page is loaded to apply the correct initial dark mode state. You can place this call at the end of your script or within a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the quick reply!
I tried implementing this though it still doesn't work. im not sure if i have done something wrong but thanks for suggestion.